# Why does my Python read more bits than I have set?

Tags: python, binary, readfile

I'm trying to read the values from a binary file but I'm having some trouble. This is what I'm doing:

```
from struct import unpack

with open("pixelValues.txt", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(8)
    foo = unpack("<Q", byte)
    print(foo)
```

When I run the program the output is `(4244912790557L,)` which doesn't make sense to me because it should be `1485102109`. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot of the file:

[image]

Comment: `byte` is quite a misleading name here for 8 bytes...

Comment: also, please post some of your data file.

Comment: Why did you call a binary file *pixelValues.txt*? Are you sure it is binary?

Comment: are you reading ASCII zeroes and ones from the text file (i.e. each *character* represents a bit)? in which case, the problem is that each "bit" actually has a value of 48 or 49...

Comment: @kindall I've added a screenshot of the file.

Comment: @xzoert I've read the file with a C program and it worked fine so I know the file is not the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect 1485102109 (i.e., what is the actual value returned by `f.read(8)`? (We don't need a screenshot; just the output of `f.read(8)` as text will do.)

Comment: @chepner What do you mean "output as text"? Also I know what the value should be because I know what I wrote to the file.

Comment: Something like "`f.read(8)` returns `'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'`" instead of a hard-to-read screenshot containing way too much extraneous data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading too much. Change `f.read(8)` to `f.read(4)` and change `unpack("<Q", byte)` to `unpack("i", byte)` and that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
pack('<Q', 1485102109)
```

Returns:

```
'\x1d\xdc\x84X\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Which is not consistent with your file.
How did you write it?

Edit:

You have written the number with a %d specifier, which means that you've written it as a 4-byte integer, not as an unsigned long long, but as an unsigned int.
You should read it like this:

```
from struct import unpack

with open("pixelValues.txt", "rb") as f:
    num = f.read(4)
    foo = unpack("<I", num)
    print(foo)
```

Comment: I wrote it with a C program. What is this supposed to return?